# How do I draw the inside of a torus?

Tags: drawing, perspective, technique

I'm trying to make a drawing of the interior of a Stanford Torus, similar to this:

[image]

Is there a way to draw the perspective of the torus accurately without using a 3D model?

Comment: Any software in particular?

Comment: Rama! I love Rama.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by drawing the axes of the walls and the ceiling.

1  Drawing the left wall bottom line (red) and top ceiling (yellow).
Drawing the right wall bottom line (blue) and top ceiling (lightblue).

2 Cmd+B to apply Blend (Object>Blend) from red to yellow first and from blue to lightblue after.

3 Define the amount of steps Object > Blend > Blend Options > Specified steps

4 Mask the blended objects on the illustration frame.

[image]

Tip: for blending is always better to have the same amount of points on each vector, on my sample just two, star and end points.

[image: vectors]

Same with arcs:

[image: arcs]